# Zero of a polynomial and divisbility

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

I have a polynomial $p(x)$, $deg(p) = n$. I know that $\alpha$ is a zero of $p(x)$. Then $(x-\alpha)|p(x)$. Is it wrong to say that $(x-\alpha)^m|p(x)$, $m  \in \mathbb{N}, m>1 $?

Comment: Well, what is $m$?

Comment: You mean $(x-\alpha)|p(x)$

Comment: @JulianMejia Yes, sorry.

Comment: @EricWofsey Now I've specified it, sorry

Comment: Is $m$ just an arbitrary number greater than $1$?  Or are you asking whether there _exists_ some such $m>1$?

Comment: Just an arbitrary number greater than 1

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's wrong to say so.

Take for example:

$$p(x) = x^3-1$$
$$=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Now note that $x=1$ is a root of $p(x)$ and hence $x-1$ divides $p(x)$. But $x^2+x+1$ has no real roots.

So the claim is false in general.

Comment: Simpler: let  $\,p(x) = x-1\,$ or $\,(x-1)x^k\,$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's too constrained to be arbitrary. One constraint is, $$m<n$$ Because, if you don't, you have to multiply by something that isn't a polynomial at some point. As [Matt Parker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pcgvv6T_bD8&app=desktop) shows us, the coeffients of a polynomial, depend on the choices of individual terms of its factorization.